# Using nested foreach in powershell

Tags: powershell, shell, loops, foreach

I am trying to running this by using foreach in powershell.

```
$var1 = @("aaa","bbb","ccc"..........)
$var2 = @("111","222","333"..........)
 foreach ($val1 in $var1) {
   echo $val1
    foreach ($val2 in $var2) {
       echo $val2
  }
}
```

```
Output of the above script is:
aaa
111
222
333
bbb
111
222
333........

But i want to print like this: 
aaa
111
bbb
222
ccc
333........
```

Is it possible by foreach? I already solve this problem by using for loop.

Comment: It's doable with a `for` loop at first glance

Comment: I already solved this problem by using for loop. Can you help by using foreach with condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var1 = @("aaa","bbb","ccc")
$var2 = @("111","222","333")

$maxCount = [math]::Max($var1.Count,$var2.Count)
```

- Using `ForEach`

```
foreach($z in 0..($maxCount-1))
{
    $var1[$z]
    $var2[$z]
}
```

- Using `For`

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $maxCount;$i++)
{
    $var1[$i]
    $var2[$i]
}
```

Comment: Nice; as an aside: I proposed enhancing PowerShell to support the following syntax (which would support an open-ended number of collections to iterate over in tandem), but it was declined: `foreach ($val1, $val2 in $var1, $var2) { ... }` - see [GitHub issue#14732)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14732).

Comment: @mklement0 would have been a great addition actually. feels bad.